# SQL Server deleted stored procedure recovery

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, disaster-recovery

I mistakenly removed all stored procedures from the database, actually executed a query but didn't notice `EXEC` statement. I recovered just 4 stored procedures from log by

```
Select 
    Convert(varchar(Max), Substring([RowLog Contents 0], 33, 
    LEN([RowLog Contents 0]))) as [Script]
from 
    fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
Where 
    [Operation] = 'LOP_DELETE_ROWS' 
    And [Context] = 'LCX_MARK_AS_GHOST'
    And [AllocUnitName] = 'sys.sysobjvalues.clst'
```

Please advice, stored procedures deleted and needs to be recovered.

Thanks

Comment: don't you have a backup of the database ?

Comment: A Stored Procedure is only source code, don't you have a versioning tool or any kind of history in your code editor?

Comment: Unfortunately, no back up for last days :(

Comment: How will you recover your data if there's no valid backup?

Comment: Correct, but as got 4 stored procedures from fn_dblog , may be there are some more options. fingers crossed ...

Comment: You say you have no backups for the last few days but do you have any backups at all? If yes, restore to a new instance and script the sprocs out to create them in this instance.

Comment: This Response may be usefull: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649708/retrieve-dropped-store-procedure-in-sql-server-before-some-hours)

Comment: This response may be useful: [Retrieve dropped store procedure in SQL server before some hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649708/retrieve-dropped-store-procedure-in-sql-server-before-some-hours)