# Retrieve dropped store procedure in SQL server before some hours

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have deleted all store procedure from my database, then I retrieved
all store procedure from last day back up. But I have lost today work, how can I retrieve today's updated store procedure? Means retrieve all store procedure before three hours.

Comment: Can you try this ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27796916/how-to-retrieve-dropped-stored-procedure-function-table-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve dropped stored procedure, function, table in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27796916/how-to-retrieve-dropped-stored-procedure-function-table-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: even this link will help : https://raresql.com/2012/12/04/sql-server-recover-the-dropped-objects-view-stored-procedure-function-trigger/

Comment: @PrabhatG, did not work.

Comment: @Shohel this shows why you need to use a source control system, or at the very least maintain sql scripts for all database objects.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

To get the CREATE PROCEDURE script, in order to re-create dropped procedure, the following complex SQL script needs to be executed

```
SELECT
       CONVERT(varchar(max),
            SUBSTRING([RowLog Contents 0],
            33,
            LEN([RowLog Contents 0]))) AS Script
  FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
WHERE
       Operation
       =
       'LOP_DELETE_ROWS'
   AND
       Context
       =
       'LCX_MARK_AS_GHOST'
   AND
       AllocUnitName
       =
       'sys.sysobjvalues.clst'
   AND [TRANSACTION ID] IN (SELECT DISTINCT
                                   [TRANSACTION ID]
                              FROM sys.fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
                            WHERE
                                  Context IN ('LCX_NULL')
                              AND Operation IN ('LOP_BEGIN_XACT')
                              AND
                                   [Transaction Name]
                                   =
                                   'DROPOBJ'
                              AND CONVERT(nvarchar(11), [Begin Time])
                    BETWEEN
                        '2013/07/31'
                    AND
                        '2013/08/1')
   AND
       SUBSTRING([RowLog Contents 0], 33, LEN([RowLog Contents 0])) <> 0;
GO
```